# Difference between `is` and `=`?

Tags: prolog

I have defined these two plus predicates:

```
plus1(A, B, C):- C is A + B.
plus2(A, B, C):- C = A + B.
```

As expected, `plus1(4, 5, X)` gives the result `X = 9`.

But `plus2(4, 5, X)` gives the result `X = 4+5`, which is not wrong, but I had expected the result `9`.

So why does it not perform any calculation, what is the difference between `is` and `=`, and when should I use what?

Comment: `is` evaluates the numerical expression to the right. Whereas `=` is unification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to leave this question without an answer.

As *Willem Van Onsem* has commented, `is` is for evaluates the numerical expressions while `=` is for unification.

I also found [this article](http://learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5) about unification for future readers with the same question.